# Why Regex statement inverting isn't working?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, lambda, split, re2

This regex marks all words that start with capital letters:

```
[A-ZÖÄÜ]+[a-zäüöß]*\b
```

But how can I reverse this so that all words that start with lowercase letters are marked?
This one is not working:

```
[^A-ZÖÄÜ]+[a-zäüöß]*\b
```

[image]

Here are some sentences for testing:

```
Teurer Dänemark-Urlaub hohe Stromkosten für Ferienhäuser
Top- Ökonom warnt  In der Schweiz bahnt sich ein globales Banken-Beben an!
Maisel kauft Weismainer Püls-Bräu
```

Comment: whats the desired output?

Comment: The first pattern needs to start with `\b`. Otherwise, it does _not_ **only** match words starting with a capital letter. As to the second one, do you want all the letters to be lowercase? If so, then just remove the `[^A-ZÖÄÜ]+` part and add `\b`. That would be `\b[a-zäüöß]+\b`

Comment: The desired output is to delete all words that starts with lowercase. \b at the end is working fine here (see image).

Comment: @user3392296 [Are you sure?](https://regex101.com/r/dQ30xj/1)

Comment: @Palestine I understand, thank you. But that shouldn't be a problem, since it's not the case that lowercase letters are still included before uppercase letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The desired output is to delete all words that starts with lowercase

use:

```
=INDEX(TEXTJOIN(" ", 1, LAMBDA(x, 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(x&"", "^[a-zäüöß]"),,x))(SPLIT(A1, " "&CHAR(10)))))
```

[image]

Comment: @user3392296 answer updated

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is working fine. The only thing is, there must not be any numbers in the sentences.

Comment: @user3392296 for that you can change `REGEXMATCH(x` to `REGEXMATCH(x&""`